# Multiple RSS feeds into one channel

Tags: rss, spring-integration

I've been looking into consuming multiple RSS feeds with Spring Integration. I followed the integration guide here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/integration/ which is great.

Is it possible to have multiple inbound channel adaptors (for multiple feeds) writing into one channel?

Also is it possible to use the channel adaptor ID within the data to identify the feed (e.g. Spring Blog)?

Any sample code would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just give the channel adapter an `id` and name the channel (if there is no `channel`, the `id` becomes the adapter's channel name). You can feed multiple adapters to the same channel. Add a header enricher to identify the source...

```
<feed:inbound-channel-adapter id="spring"
         channel="springblog" url="http://spring.io/blog.atom" auto-startup="${auto.startup:true}">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
</feed:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:header-enricher input-channel="springblog" output-channel="news">
    <int:header name="source" value="spring.blog"/>
</int:header-enricher>

<int:transformer
    input-channel="news"
    expression=
      "headers['source'] + ':' + payload.title + ' @ ' + payload.link + '#{systemProperties['line.separator']}'"
    output-channel="file"/>

<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="file"
    mode="APPEND"
    charset="UTF-8"
    directory="/tmp/si"
    filename-generator-expression="'${feed.file.name:SpringBlog}'"/>
```

Using the newer Java DSL instead of XML, this would be...

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow blog() throws Exception {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from(new FeedEntryMessageSource(new URL(BLOG_URI), "blog"), e -> e.id("blog").poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)))
        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("source", "spring.blog"))
        .channel("news")
        .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow newsFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("news")
        .transform("headers['source'] + ':' + payload.title + ' @ ' + payload.link + '" + newline + "'") // SpEL
        .handle(Files.outboundAdapter(new File("/tmp/si/"))
            .fileNameExpression("'SpringBlogDSL'")
            .fileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.APPEND))
        .get();
}
```

**EDIT**

Dynamic flow registration...

```
@Autowired
private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

...

    IntegrationFlow newFLow = IntegrationFlows
        .from(new FeedEntryMessageSource(new URL(BLOG_URI), "blog"), e -> e.id("blog").poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)))
        .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("source", "spring.blog"))
        .channel("news")
        .get();
    this.flowContent.registration(newFlow).register();
```

See the [dynamic-tcp-client sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced/dynamic-tcp-client) for a complete example.

Comment: Thanks Gary this is a great help. Thinking about it, I might want to create this as a microservice which allows feeds to be added dynamically at runtime. Is this possible? I am assuming there will have to be a separate inbound channel adapter for each feed so it can scale to handle a large amount of feeds.

Comment: Yes, you can add flows dynamically; see the edit to my answer. If you use XML configuration you have to create a child application context; see the dynamic-ftp sample for an example of that. It's README talks about using child contexts for message sources.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I'll have a go this week. Great to have this support.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect several channel adapters to the same message channel. Actually any producer can send to any channel and having your request about additional info, I'd suggest to have after each feed Inbound Adapter a header enricher to populate a desired characteristic. And after that you can send to  that single channel for processing.